# Colapsar lista al hacer click en un elemento

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una lista de acordeon que al hacer click, muestra y/o oculta el texto, de momento funciona mi unico problema es que necesito que al pulsar sobre un elemento, los que estan abiertos se colapsen, no se si tenga que usar un condicional, pero igual no se como plantearlo, para que colapsen los demas elementos que ya estan mostrados.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.items__content');
const title = document.querySelectorAll('.items__title');
const text = document.querySelectorAll('.items__text');

for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    
    items[index].addEventListener("click", () => {
   
        title[index].classList.toggle("items__title--bold");
        text[index].classList.toggle("items__text--mostrar");
    });
}
```

```css
.items__text {
    height: 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .1s ease;
}

.items__body > .items__text--mostrar {
    height: unset;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    
}

.items__content > .items__title--bold {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.items__content > .items__title--bold:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
        <div class="items">
            <div id="items__content" class="items__content">
              <p class="items__title">Titulo 1</p>
            </div>
          <div class="items__body">
            <p id="items__text" class="items__text">Texto 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="items">
            <div id="items__content" class="items__content">
              <p class="items__title">Titulo 2</p>
            </div>
          <div class="items__body">
            <p class="items__text">Texto 2.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bastaría con modificar un poco tu JS, aunque como sugerencia deberías de usar un estándar para nombrar tus clases (En css el estándar es class="name large-class-name" separados con guiones medios), además de fijarte que en este caso tienes elementos con el mismo id (Aquí ya quité ese error)

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.items__content');
    const title = document.querySelectorAll('.items__title');
    const text = document.querySelectorAll('.items__text');

    for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {

        items[index].addEventListener("click", () => {
            const hide = document.querySelectorAll('.items__text--mostrar');
            if(hide)
                for (let element of hide) {
                    element.className = element.className.replace(/ items__text--mostrar/g, '');
                }
            title[index].classList.toggle("items__title--bold");
            text[index].classList.toggle("items__text--mostrar");
        });
    }
```

```css
.items__text {
        height: 0;
        margin: 5px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all .1s ease;
    }

    .items__body>.items__text--mostrar {
        height: unset;
        padding-bottom: 1em;

    }

    .items__content>.items__title--bold {
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .items__content>.items__title--bold:hover {
        color: #000;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Toggle</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="items__content">
            <p class="items__title">Titulo 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="items__body">
            <p id="items__text" class="items__text">Texto 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items">
        <div class="items__content">
            <p class="items__title">Titulo 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="items__body">
            <p class="items__text">Texto 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funciona, aunque ahora si hago click en un elemento y vuelvo a clickear en el mismo no se colapsa, intente agregar el else, pero no funciona